# Can I use one of standard Outlook's previewers to preview other file types?

Tags: outlook, preview, outlook-2010

Outlook's "Windows TXT previewer" only previews attachments with extension .txt.
Is there a way to tell Outlook (2010) to use "Windows TXT previewer" on other type attachments?

For example, I would like to use it to preview .csv files and some other extensions that are just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, you have to change some entries in the Registry. Preview HAndlers have GUIDs that are stored in the Registry. For each filetype, if there is one available, there is a preview handler.

For .csv files you need the Preview Handler from Microsoft Excel since a .csv file is Excel.

Comment: The csv files I need to view are basically texts, text previewer will work fine. But even so, how exactly I tell Excel previewer to view .csv files?

Comment: Normally the Previewer would have a standaard handler registered when it's installed. When installing Office programs there will be preview handlers installed automatically. Which PreviewHandler Control do you use? I need to know, otherwise I can't exactly give a definite answer.... I found a tool on the net a while ago which lets you manage the installed preview handlers for each known file type on your computer. I can send you the tool but I'm not sure if your allowed to post an emailadres or something on here.

Comment: I am not sure what PreviewHandler control is, but I think I had enough keywords form this discussion to find this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144143(v=vs.85).aspx
Apparently (did not know that), there is semi-standard Windows preview framwork, which Outlook relies on for its own previews.

Comment: I wrote up my solution as separate answer. Thanks for staying with me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a registry change:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.CSV\ShellEx]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.CSV\ShellEx\{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}]
@="{1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}"
```

Here {1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22} is GUID for text previewer (listed among HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PreviewHandlers) and {8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f} is special ID that identifies previewer for this filetype. It may be different for other verisons of windows, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144143(v=vs.85).aspx may or may not  have more details

Comment: FYI The registry change is that you need to add the above keys.

Answer (score 1):

Another method: **install Preview Handlers**.

1. Download [PreviewHandlers2007_01](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/2/7/f279e71e-efb0-4155-873d-5554a0608523/PreviewHandlers2007_01.exe) and run it.

   - A folder called PreviewHandlers will be created
   - Don't worry because of that file name. That file containing "2007" worked very good for Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010.
2. Go to PreviewHandlers\Installer and run **Install**

   - Probably it won't work because of Microsoft Visual J# is missing.
   - Download [Microsoft Visual J# Version 2.0 Redistributable Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=4712) and install it (probably it appears as **vjredist** in your download folder)
   - Run the **Install** file again.
3. Restart Outlook

You will be able to see the content of that **CSV** attachment as a **table**.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to preview files like .csv, .log etc. within Outlook message panel, it is directly related with default program in Windows (operating system).

So, in Windows Explorer add default program:
 - open the folder containing .csv file
 - **right click** on the file and choios in the menu "*Open With...*"
 - Choose Default Program
 - Select desired programe (Notepad++, Excel, etc.)
 - **Restart** Outlook